# How can I make the image get the `left: 0` style with a transition?

Tags: javascript, class, transition, motion

I have an image here which initially has a `left: 100%`, I want it to be moved to `left: 0` when the method `move` is executed, but with a transition so that the motion will be seen,

I already gave a `transition: 700ms` to the `.img` but that doesn't seem to work, anybody has an idea how I can make that transition work?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {

    let sliderWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-wrapper')[0];

    class Image {
        sliderWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-wrapper')[0];
        constructor(_src) {
            this.src = _src;
            this.width = `${window.getComputedStyle(sliderWrapper).width}`;
            this.move()
        }
    }
    Image.prototype.move = function () {
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute("src", this.src);
        img.setAttribute("width", this.width);
        img.classList.add('img')
        img.style.left = '0';
        sliderWrapper.appendChild(img);
    }
    let img = new Image('http://placehold.jp/24/cc9999/993333/150x100.png')

});
```

```css
*{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .slider-wrapper{
            position: relative;
            max-width: 60%;
            height: 350px;
            margin: 70px auto;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
        .img{
            position: absolute;
            left: 100%;
            top: 0;
            transition: 700ms;
        }
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: The example doesn't have any code to transition? Please may you make sure the question includes a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add setTimeout(...) in your javascript code:

```js
    Image.prototype.move = function () {
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute("src", this.src);
        img.setAttribute("width", this.width);
        img.classList.add('img')
       
        sliderWrapper.appendChild(img); // you need to append this before you set "left: 0"
     
        // use setTimeout to animate the image
        setTimeout(() => {
            img.style.left = '0'; // now this will animate the image
        }, 100);
    }
```

**[EDIT]:** No need to type

```js
sliderWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-wrapper')[0];
```

in the class `Image` because it is already been declared at the top.